# How to build android-gif-drawable lib to .so file

Tags: android, android-ndk

In the android-gif-drawable lib source, it doesn't contain any Andorid.mk or Application.mk file, as the result when I use the ndk-build, it returns some error like this

`Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it`

I am really poor in ndk, is there anyone could help me?

You may wonder why I need to build the so file, the reason is that: in my project, I already have another .so file lib, it seems that when I use the gradle to add the gif lib(compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.6') my another ".so" file can't be found, and my app error.

So I now try to build the gif lib to a ".so" file, I hope this way could be help.

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion of android-gif-drawable shouldn't lead to the removal of your other .so files. Can you post your current build.gradle file ?

Amyway, you can directly get android-gif-drawable .so files from the jni folder that is inside the lib's .aar: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/koral/maven/pl/droidsonroids/gif/android-gif-drawable/1.1.6/android-gif-drawable-1.1.6.aar

Else, in orer to rebuild it yourself, you can can clone the github repo and build it using gradle. If you want to use the ndk-build command, you'll have to write the Makefiles.

Comment: Thanks! I  have get the .so files from the jni folder that is inside the lib's .aar.